# Ansible send email using dynamic file name

Tags: email, variables, ansible

I need to use Ansible to copy from the remote server the log files, rename them and send by emails as attachments.

I created this playbook:

```
---
 - hosts: WebAccessServers
   vars:
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d') }}"
   tasks:
     - name: copy web access log file from Web servers to Ansible Server and rename it
       fetch:
        src: /var/www/html/mywebapp/logs/access.log
        dest: /tmp/{{ date }}_{{ inventory_hostname }}_access.log
        flat: yes
        ignore_errors: true
        delegate_to: localhost

 - hosts: localhost
   vars:
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d') }}"
   tasks:
     - name: create variable for the attachments
       shell: "ls /tmp/{{ date }}_*.log"
       register: command_output
     - debug: msg="{{ command_output.stdout_lines }}"

     - name: Send Emails to a bunch of users, with Playbook Report as an attachment.
       mail:
        host: mysmtp.mydomain.com
        port: 25
        subject: Ansible Playbook Report
        body: This is an Email generated using Ansible after execution of task.
        from: ansibbe@gmydomain.com (Ansible Automates)
        to:
        - John Brown <j.ba@mydomain.com>
        attach:
        - "{{  command_output.stdout_lines }}"
        headers:
        - Reply-To=ansible@domain.com
        - X-Special="Write something special about this Email"
        charset: us-ascii
```

If I run it I receive this output:

> PLAY [WebAccess]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
> ************************************************************************************************************************************ ok: [Server-1] ok: [Server-2] ok: [Server-3]
>
> TASK [copy custom web access log file from Web servers]
> ********************************************************************************************* ok: [Server-1] ok: [Server-2] ok: [Server-3]
>
> PLAY [localhost]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
> ************************************************************************************************************************************ ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [create variable for the attachments]
> **************************************************************************************************************** changed: [localhost]
>
> TASK [debug]
> ********************************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [localhost] => {
> "msg": [
> "/tmp/20200923_Server-1_access.log",
> "/tmp/20200923_Server-2_access.log",
> "/tmp/20200923_Server-3_access.log"
> ] }
> TASK [Send Emails to a bunch of users, with Playbook Report as an attachment.]
> **************************************************************************** An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full
> traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: expected str, bytes or
> os.PathLike object, not list   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
> {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to send mail: can't attach file
> ['/tmp/20200923_Server-1_access.log',
> '/tmp/20200923_Server-2_access.log',
> '/tmp/20200923_Server-3_access.log']: expected str, bytes or
> os.PathLike object, not list", "rc": 1}
> PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************ Server-1  : ok=    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0
> rescued=0    ignored=0 Server-2  : ok=2   changed=0    unreachable=0
> failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0 Server-3  : ok=2
> changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0
> ignored=0 localhost : ok=3   changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
> skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Where is the best way to assign dynamically and recursively the attach in the email?
Thanks for the support.
Marco

Comment: I'm guessing the email is fine and your email client is doing something stupid, If you are on Windows, try not to be; or if you have to, try to find an editor which can display files with Unix line endings.

Comment: Hi tripleee, I'm on Linux, and my problem is to assign dinalically more attachs to the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my work solution:

```
---
 - hosts: myapp
   vars:
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d') }}"
   tasks:
     - name: copy access_allowed log file from MyApp servers
       fetch:
        src: /var/www/html/myapp/logs/access_allowed.log
        dest: /tmp/{{ date }}_{{ inventory_hostname }}_access_allowed.log
        flat: yes
        ignore_errors: true
        delegate_to: localhost
     - name: copy access_denied log file from MyApp servers
       fetch:
        src: /var/www/html/myapp/logs/access_denied.log
        dest: /tmp/{{ date }}_{{ inventory_hostname }}_access_denied.log
        flat: yes
        ignore_errors: true
        delegate_to: localhost

     - name: Ansible delete log file
       shell: sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/myapp/logs/access*.log

 - hosts: localhost
   vars:
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d') }}"
   tasks:
     - name: create variable for the attachments
       shell: "ls /tmp/{{ date }}_*.log"
       register: command_output

     - name: Send Emails to a bunch of users, with Playbook Report as an attachment.
       mail:
        host: my.smtp.local
        port: 25
        subject: Ansible Playbook Report
        body: This is an Email generated using Ansible after execution of task.
        from: ansible@mydomain.com (Ansible Automates)
        to: John Brow <JB@mydomain.com>
        attach: "{{ command_output.stdout_lines | join(',') }}"
        headers:
        - Reply-To=ansible@mydomain.com
        - X-Special="Write something special about this Email"
        charset: us-ascii

     - name: Ansible delete log file
       shell: sudo rm -rf /tmp/*access*.log
```

Answer (score 1):

As prompted by the error message, `to`, `attach` and `headers` are not supposed to be lists.

- `to`: The email-address(es) the mail is being sent to. **This is a comma-separated list, which may contain address and phrase portions.**
- `headers`: **A vertical-bar-separated list of headers** which should be added to the message. Each individual header is specified as `header=value` (see example below).
- `attach`: **A space-separated list of pathnames of files** to attach to the message. Attached files will have their content-type set to application/octet-stream.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/mail_module.html, emphasis mine*</sup>

- For the `to`, if you have only one recipient `to: John Brown <john.brown@example.org>` and if you have multiple `to: John Brown <john.brown@example.org>, John Doe <john.doe@example.org>`
- For the `headers`, if you have only one `headers: 'Reply-To=ansible@example.org'` and if you have multiple `headers: 'Reply-To=ansible@example.org|X-Special="Write something special about this Email"'`
- For `attach` since you are taking it from another the output of another task, using Jinja [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join) filter allows you to convert your list into a space-separated string representation of the said list.

So you `mail` task should actually be:

```yaml
- name: Send Emails to a bunch of users, with Playbook Report as an attachment.
  mail:
    host: mysmtp.mydomain.com
    port: 25
    subject: Ansible Playbook Report
    body: This is an Email generated using Ansible after execution of task.
    from: ansibbe@gmydomain.com (Ansible Automates)
    to: John Brown <j.ba@mydomain.com>
    attach: "{{ command_output.stdout_lines | join(' ') }}"
    headers: 'Reply-To=ansible@group-miki.com|X-Special="Write something special about this Email"'
    charset: us-ascii
```

Comment: I tried to change my script add attach, But I received this error:
An exception occurred during task execution. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/20200924_Server-1_access.log /tmp/20200924_Server-2_access.log /tmp/20200924_Server-3_access.log'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to send mail: can't attach file /tmp/xxx.log /tmp/xxx.log /tmp/xxx.log:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/20200924_asia-1_access.log /tmp/20200924_BCA-PRD-RVPX01_access.log /tmp/20200924_BCC-PRD-RVPX02_access.log'", "rc": 1}

Answer (score 0):

---

```
  tasks:

    - name: Create variable for the attachments
      shell: "ls *.log"
      register: log_files
    - debug: msg="{{ log_files.stdout_lines | list | join(',') }}"
```

```
- name: Email logs
  community.general.mail:
```

```
        attach: "{{ log_files.stdout_lines | list | join(',') }}"
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?